# Сделать вырез на css

Tags: css, clip-path

Пытаюсь вырезать буквы в `div` на чистом `CSS`, использую — `clip-path`, но  полностью вырезать не получается.

```css
body {
  background: #262626;
}

.education-feedback {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background-image: url('../img/back-bot.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

.line-trans {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  left: 5%;
  top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-47deg);
}

.line-trans img {
  width: 316px;
  height: 17px;
}

.form_feedback {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  clip-path: polygon(21% 31%, 10% 5%, 0 40%, 0 100%, 20% 100%, 48% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 80%, 100% 42%, 100% 0, 80% 0%, 31% 0);
}

.form_feedback input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #059805;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.form_feedback .btn-order {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #059805 33%, #4dbd4d 66%, #1db11d);
  color: #fff;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 15px 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.name_feddback {
  position: relative;
}

.name_feddback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 6px;
}

.phone_feedback {
  position: relative;
}

.phone_feedback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 6px;
}

.email_feedback {
  position: relative;
}

.email_feedback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="education-feedback">
  <div class="line-trans"><img src="img/line.png"></div>
  <div class="form_feedback">
    <div class="name_feddback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>

    <div class="phone_feedback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="Телефон">
    </div>

    <div class="email_feedback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
    <p><button class="btn-order">Заказать курс</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вырез буквы N и M -**

[image: Вырез буквы N и M]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Псевдоэлементы спешат на помощь!

```css
body {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529926279675-c72f1da4eb2a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=86eceef4b033a911a312516dc81ccc58&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
}

.line-trans {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  left: 5%;
  top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-47deg);
}

.line-trans img {
  width: 316px;
  height: 17px;
}

.education-feedback {
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.form_feedback {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.form_feedback::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid white;
}

.form_feedback::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 26px solid white;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.angle:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  height: 80px;
}

.angle:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: inherit;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.angle:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid white;
  height: inherit;
}

.angle:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  height: 80px;
}

.angle:last-child::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: inherit;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.angle:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -70px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 45px solid white;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -85px;
  border-right: 13px solid white;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}

.triangle::before,
.triangle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle::before {
  top: 30px;
  left: -14px;
  border-left: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid white;
}

.triangle::after {
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid white;
  top: 30px;
  left: -59px;
}

.add {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: -84px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.add::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform: skew(-23deg);
}

.add::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -28px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: 6px;
}

.form_feedback input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #059805;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.form_feedback .btn-order {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #059805 33%, #4dbd4d 66%, #1db11d);
  color: #fff;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 15px 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form_feedback input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #059805;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.form_feedback .btn-order {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #059805 33%, #4dbd4d 66%, #1db11d);
  color: #fff;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 15px 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  z-index: 1;
}

.name_feddback {
  position: relative;
}

.name_feddback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 6px;
}

.phone_feedback {
  position: relative;
}

.phone_feedback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 6px;
}

.email_feedback {
  position: relative;
}

.email_feedback img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="education-feedback">
  <div class="line-trans"><img src="img/line.png"></div>
  <div class="form_feedback">
    <div class="angle"></div>
    <div class="name_feedback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>

    <div class="phone_feedback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="Телефон">
    </div>

    <div class="email_feedback">
      <input type="" name="" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
    <p><button class="btn-order">Заказать курс</button></p>
    <div class="angle">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="add"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший ответ держи плюсик

Comment: да получилось, только с буквой - M не совсем выходит

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов, хорошо, вскоре добавлю с буквой М

Comment: Ок, сразу дам награду тогда

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов, добавлена буква `M`

Comment: Мне кажется, или как-то сложно?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне вообще эта затея не совсем по душе, не люблю делать подобные вещи, слишком много элементов пришлось создавать, твой ответ получше будет в этом плане=)

Answer (score 6):

`clip-path` можно совмещать с `calc`. Надо просто задать все величины фиксированными (т. е. не в процентах), а для нижнего края при помощи `calc` вычесть их из 100%.

Буква `W` вверху слева:

```
clip-path: polygon(1em 1em, 2.5em 1em, 3.5em 4em, 4.5em 1em, 5.5em 1em, 6.5em 4em, 7.5em 1em, 9em 1em, 7em 7em, 6em 7em, 5em 4em, 4em 7em, 3em 7em, 1em 1em);
```

Буква `M` внизу справа получается из неё лёгким преобразованием

```js
console.log(
  "1em 1em, 2.5em 1em, 3.5em 4em, 4.5em 1em, 5.5em 1em, 6.5em 4em, 7.5em 1em, 9em 1em, 7em 7em, 6em 7em, 5em 4em, 4em 7em, 3em 7em, 1em 1em"
  .replace(/([^ ,]+)(,?)/g, "calc(100% - $1)$2")
)
```

Это всё вставляется в `clip-path` и дополняется прямоугольником и парой точек:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red);
}

div {
  padding: 1em 10em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;

  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    1em 1em, 2.5em 1em, 3.5em 4em, 4.5em 1em, 5.5em 1em, 6.5em 4em, 7.5em 1em, 9em 1em, 7em 7em, 6em 7em, 5em 4em, 4em 7em, 3em 7em, 1em 1em,
    0 0,
    calc(100% - 1em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 2.5em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 3.5em) calc(100% - 4em), calc(100% - 4.5em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 5.5em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 6.5em) calc(100% - 4em), calc(100% - 7.5em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 9em) calc(100% - 1em), calc(100% - 7em) calc(100% - 7em), calc(100% - 6em) calc(100% - 7em), calc(100% - 5em) calc(100% - 4em), calc(100% - 4em) calc(100% - 7em), calc(100% - 3em) calc(100% - 7em), calc(100% - 1em) calc(100% - 1em),
    0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0
  );
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
Пытаюсь вырезать буквы в div на чистом CSS, использую — clip-path, но полностью вырезать не получается
Пытаюсь вырезать буквы в div на чистом CSS, использую — clip-path, но полностью вырезать не получается
Пытаюсь вырезать буквы в div на чистом CSS, использую — clip-path, но полностью вырезать не получается
</div>
```

Comment: Да, круто получилось)